# How many copies of Magicka do we need to play co-op?

Tags: magicka

To play the Magicka campaign in co-op mode, do we need to buy a copy each, or is one enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play locally with one copy of the game, one person playing on keyboard and 3 on gamepads.

According to the [Wiki](http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/Multiplayer):

> Magicka is rather unique in its handling of multiple players. Up to 4
>   players can either connect via a network, or directly on one machine
>   using a USB Gamepad.

Comment: Magicka with joysticks? That doesn't sound like it'd be fun.

Comment: @lunboks Unfortunately it is not very easy to cast complex spells, but its doable with practice. The keyboard provides a better playing experience.

Comment: @lunboks Sorry, english is not my main language and looks like joysticks are a specific kind of gamepads, those which are even harder to play with. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks! What kind of gamepads work? Most posts just say "gamepads".

Comment: @Tim Xbox controllers work for sure, but I think any will do, such as those that looks like Playstation's controllers.

Comment: I completed the campaign with three players, we used PS3 controllers with MotionInJoy set to emulate x360-controllers. The game is quite playable, although spellcasting is noticeably slower than with a keyboard since you use the right thumbstick for selecting elements (which works a lot better than it sounds, to be fair). I'd still recommend you give it a go, playing the game with more than two people on a couch more than makes up for the slower controls.

Comment: do you need multiple copies of the dlc maps to play co-op on them online? or is it ok if just the host has them?